# Sqlite Update columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have 5 columns in my table : id, x, y, source, distance.

For every id, i want to find the nearest x & y values and update that value in the distance field along with its id in source.

I'm able to update the distance with the below query:

```
UPDATE item SET distance = ( SELECT MIN( ABS (a.x - item.x) + ABS (a.y - item.y) ) 
FROM item AS a WHERE a.id != item.id )
```

However i'm unable to update the source because sqlite does not support multiple column update from a single select.

When i try to put the query in the where condition, i get the error, no such column as item.x

```
UPDATE item SET link = ( SELECT id FROM item AS a WHERE a.id != item.id 
ORDER BY ABS (a.x - item.x) + ABS (a.y - item.y) LIMIT 1 )
```

How do i resolve my query ?

Comment: Even if i use it in a single query, i still have to pass the 2nd query. This fails with the error no such column as item.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, SQLite does not allow to reference the outer table in an ORDER BY clause.

You can work around this by adding the distance calculation to the SELECT clause. This requires wrapping another subquery around this to return only one column:

```
 UPDATE item
 SET link = ( SELECT id
              FROM ( SELECT id,
                            ABS (a.x - item.x) + ABS (a.y - item.y)
                     FROM item AS a
                     WHERE a.id != item.id
                     ORDER BY 2
                     LIMIT 1 ))
```

---

If you update the `link` column first, you can then use that value to compute the distance without having to search the entire table again:

```
UPDATE item
SET distance = ( SELECT ABS (a.x - item.x) + ABS (a.y - item.y)
                 FROM item AS a
                 WHERE a.id = item.link )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get the closest id for each record using logic like this:

```
select i.*,
       (select id
        from item i2
        where i2.id <> i.id
        order by abs(i2.x - i.x) + abs(i2.y - i.y)
       ) as closest_id
from item i;
```

You can put this into a `with` clause to simplify the rest of the query:

```
with closest as (
      select i.*,
             (select id
              from item i2
              where i2.id <> i.id
              order by abs(i2.x - i.x) + abs(i2.y - i.y)
             ) as closest_id
      from item i
     )
update item
    set link = (select closest_id from closest where closest.id = item.id),
        distance = (select abs(i2.x - c.x) + abs(i2.y - c.y)
                    from closest c join
                         item i2
                         on c.closest_id = i2.id
                    where closest.id = item.id
                   );
```

EDIT:

If `with` is not available, you can do this without the `with`, just by using the subquery multiple times.  However, I would suggest two updates:

```
update item
    set link = (select id
                from item i2
                where i2.id <> item.id
                order by abs(i2.x - item.x) + abs(i2.y - item.y)
               );

update item
    set distance = (select abs(i2.x - item.x) + abs(i2.y - item.y) 
                    from item i2
                    where i2.id = item.link
                   );
```

Comment: WITH is not available in most Android versions.